# Dot product versus matrix product for vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have a quick notational question:
Given the two vectors $\vec{a}$, being $1 \times 5$ dimensional, and $\vec{b}$, being $5 \times  1$ dimensional. I often see that the dot product would be written as $\vec{a}^T*\vec{b}$. However, would it not be equivalent to simply assume matrix multiplication and hence to write $\vec{a}*\vec{b}$ - without transposing $\vec{a}$?
We would still end up with the $1 \times 1$ scalar as before..

Thanks

Comment: You would, but your $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ do not live in the same space, so this is not a dot product.

Comment: You mean that $\vec{a}^T*\vec{b}$ is not a dot product to begin with? What is it then?

Comment: Your vector $\vec a$ lives in $\mathcal M_{1\times 5}$ and $\vec b$ in $\mathcal M_{5\times 1}$. You can multiply these matrices, but it's not a dot product. On ther other hand, you cannot multiply ${}^{\mathrm t}\vec a$ and $\vec b$

Comment: I am not following. There are plenty of cases where we see the inner product calculated as $a^T b$, which suggests that the original $\vec{a}$ is not in the same space as $\vec{b}$. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Precisely, $\vec a$ *has* to be  in the same space as $\vec b$ it you use its transpose. Otherwise you can't multiply them. In your post this transpose is a $5\times 1$ matrix: you can't multiply it (on the right) by another  $5\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: I think I got it now (maybe I was not clear regarding which multiplication I meant): 1. So, for the dot product, a has to be transposed, s.t. we get two vectors (namely$\vec{a^T}$ and $\vec{b}$ which are both 5x1 dim 2. For matrix multiplication however, a's number of columns has to match b's columns of row, so we have simply $\vec{a}*\vec{b}$, which is however multiplication in another space than what we had in 1. Is this what you mean?:)

Comment: Yes, but in your post you wrote $\vec a$ is $1\times 5$, instead of $5\times 1$. I guess you messed up the vector and its transpose.

Comment: whaaaat. if a would be 5 x 1, then its transpose would be 1 x 5, which wouldn't go for the inner product with b which is 5 x 1 (and (5,1)(5,1) would not make sense for matrix multiplication either)!

Comment: For  dot product, you use a matrix multiplication  $(1\times5$ ($\leftrightarrow{}^{\mathrm t}\vec a$) by $5\times1$ ($\leftrightarrow \vec b)$). This works quite fine.